# Printing struct value from a list using iterator

Tags: c++, list, struct

I am having trouble with printing values from my struct Pages. I am trying to print the value of segment in Pages from a list of pages. The assignSegments() method is assigning values to the variable segment. This is the error I am getting.  ‘std::list::iterator’ has no member named ‘segment’

Here is the code I have so far. If you need more code from me just let me know.

Following code is in my main

```
Process child;
char c = 'A';
c = c+i;
child.letter = c;

assignSegments(child.childPages, child.letter, CreateRandomNumber());

for(list<Pages>::iterator iter = child.childPages.begin(); iter != child.childPages.end(); i++)
{
     cout << *iter.segment << endl; // having trouble printing here
}
```

Here are my structs that I am using.

```
struct Pages
{    
    string segment;
    char validBit;
    int refByte;
    Pages * pagePointer;
    int* memoryPointer;
};

struct Process
{    
    char letter;
    list<Pages> childPages;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `cout << iter->segment << endl;` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`operator.` has a higher precedence over `operator*`, so `iter.segment` will be evaluated first, obviously it's not what you want.

Reference for [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

you can change

```
cout << *iter.segment << endl;
```

to

```
cout << (*iter).segment << endl;
```

or just

```
cout << iter->segment << endl;
```